# String replace expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have the following string:

```js
var myString = "Name: ";

function replaceName(str, name) {
  return str.replace(/Name:/gi, "Name:" + name);
}

myString = replaceName("Name: ", "Joe");
myString = replaceName("Name: ", "Jane");
```

I want to replace the entire line each time a new name is added. The above keeps appending the name to the end of the string.

How can I replace the name each time `str.replace` is called?

Comment: You are asking it to replace to `"Name:" + "Joe"`. What's the desired output you want?

Comment: Exactly... It works fine...

Comment: @Rory if you call the function a second time with a different value it will append it.

Comment: Eh, where's the second time and where's the function?

Comment: @adam78 yes - I just realised. It would have been more helpful if you'd outlined that in the question. However with the required logic it would make more sense to just create a new string in each instance rather than making a replacement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you could have mentioned clearly that calling the function second time messes up. And secondly, there's no functions in your code, so you need to tell which line is messing up. I understood the question with the help of [Rory McCrossan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519413/rory-mccrossan) and here's the answer.

I changed the code and using this RegEx worked:

```js
var str = "Name: ";
str = str.replace(/Name:.*/gi, "Name:" + "Joe");
console.log(str);
str = str.replace(/Name:.*/gi, "Name:" + "Prav");
console.log(str);
```

**Explanation for the RegEx**

[image: preview]

*psst: There's no better explanation than RegEx101...*

Comment: kindly add explanation for the regex :)

Comment: @guradio Looking good? There's no better explanation than RegEx101!

Comment: The capture group is superfluous.

Comment: @Toto Sorry, what do you mean? `:)` Eh, I agree with you. But is there any other choice other than "not using a capture group"?

Comment: The regex could be as simple as : `/Name:.*/`, no group.

Comment: @Toto Thanks mate... Updated... You are awesome! ☺ I have always been thinking it won't work without the group.